# MySQL has failed, please contact the sysadmin (the result was "mysql is not running")

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

Yesterday, we updated [cPanel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPanel) to version 11.32.2 (build 8). After the update, the MySQL server went down and it doesn't restart. MySQL is down now. MySQL version is 5.5.

I tried to reinstall MySQL, but it didn't work. The server is based on [CentOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS).

What can we do?

Comment: Check the system logs and the database's logs for more detailed errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by checking the MySQL error log, whilst attempting to start MySQL

```
tail -n100 -F /var/lib/mysql/*.err
```

Then in another session,

```
service mysql start
```

That will give you a rough indication of why it is failing to start. It could be anything at this stage,

1. Full `/var` partition
2. `/tmp` partition non-writable (or too small)
3. `ulimit` too restrictive for `open_files` or `memory`
4. Crashed/faulty/broken tables

***My advice would be to consult a professional***, this is a Q&A site and your question is far too localised to have value/relevance to other users (without more explicit detail).